# EWS complex searchfiltercollection with multiple logical operators

Tags: exchangewebservices

can you help me, how to make a searchfiltercollection with multiple logical operators?

I would like to filter by sender and receiver in that way:
(sender1 or sender2) and (receiver1 or receiver2)

My solution doesnt work:

```
//filter email sender
ArrayList<SearchFilter> filterEmailFromArray = new ArrayList<SearchFilter>();
filterEmailFromArray.add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.Sender,new EmailAddress("sender1@email.com")));
filterEmailFromArray.add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.Sender,new EmailAddress("sender2@email.com")));
SearchFilter filterEmailFrom = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or,filterEmailFromArray);

//filter email received by
ArrayList<SearchFilter> filterEmailToArray = new ArrayList<SearchFilter>();
filterEmailToArray.add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.ReceivedBy,new EmailAddress("receiver1@email.com")));
filterEmailToArray.add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.ReceivedBy,new EmailAddress("receiver2@email.com")));
SearchFilter filterEmailTo = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or,filterEmailToArray);

//final filter
ArrayList<SearchFilter> filterExchangeArray = new ArrayList<SearchFilter>();
filterExchangeArray.add(filterEmailFrom);
filterExchangeArray.add(filterEmailTo);
SearchFilter filterExchange = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And,filterExchangeArray);
```

This filter finds me 0 results, what is wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do the first two filters work individually?

Comment: No, "received by" filter doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already said both filters work individually, but can you confirm? The reason I ask is that searching on the "received by" property is a little funky.

For example, when I try to search that property with SMTP addresses like in your example, I get zero results. If I change the value to use the "EX" type address, I get results. Like:

```
string exAddy = "/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=50320805D61A4F8CBC8F5BE113F28136-ALLIEB";
filterTo.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.ReceivedBy, new Mailbox(exAddy, "EX")));
```

Have you tried [enabling tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495632%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) and just searching with the filterEmailTo filter? I'm curious as to what the response looks like.

Comment: Yes, you are right, "received by" filter doesn't work as expected. I need a filter, which will filter by receivers email address (this email could be also gmail.com, not just exchange).

Comment: Can you give some more detail on your scenario? I believe that the received by would always be the owner of the mailbox, though maybe not for some edge cases like copying MSG files into the mailbox, etc. Are you having gmail.com mails forwarded to the Exchange mailbox?

You might want to download [EWSEditor](http://ewseditor.codeplex.com) and view the item properties to see how they are set to give a better idea of how to shape your search.

Comment: Jason, thank you very much, EWSEditor is really helpful tool. I have solved my problem by Advance Query String, where I can write "To:email@email.com" and it works :-)